# HTML: Swap TextBox for plain text but maintain layout

Tags: html, css, layout, user-interface

For a readonly view, I want to swap textboxes for plain text (because it looks nicer than `disabled` textboxes.

However, plain text doesn't have the same margin/border/padding values, so the text no longer aligns with labels, where the textbox did.

What's an appropriate technique for making the plain text still line up with the existing `label`?

Comment: Why not just *style* the disabled text-areas/text-inputs appropriately? Also, a pet peeve, there is *no* `textbox` element: there's `<textarea></textarea>` and `<input type="text" />`.

Comment: Because disabled text inputs are fugly.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in an `display:inline-block` div. `vertical-align:baseline` might help as well. Depending on the markup of the label you would need to change the label to an inline-block as well.
(If you could provide some markup it might be easier to assist. jsfiddle maybe?)